# Python urllib2 multiple try statement on urlopen()

Tags: python, urllib2

So, simply I want to be able to run a for across a list of URLs, if one fails then I want to continue on to try the next.

I've tried using the following but sadly it throws and exception if the first URL doesn't work.

```
servers = ('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com')
for server in servers:
    try:
        u = urllib2.urlopen(server)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    raise
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exception is it throwing?  You may have to catch more errors than just urllib2.URLError

Comment: Throws urllib2.URLError


"urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>"

Answer (score 0):

```
servers = ('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com')
for server in servers:
    try:
        u = urllib2.urlopen(server)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    raise
```

This code breaks out of the loop if the url connection *doesn't* raise an error (`else: break` part).

Do you want the 2nd one used *only* if the first fails?

*edit: I thought that the `else:` following the for loop should `raise` because of the `break`, but in my quick test that didn't work ... because my understanding of [for/else](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) was wrong*

Comment: The for should only continue if the first url does cause an exception, this should be the case for any number of URLS in the list.

E.g. if 1 and 2 fail then the third should be tried.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turned out to be user error. I was trying stupid domains like "wegwegwe.com" but I never actually had a usable domain in the list, so eventually it did just raise the exception.

User error.